# Can I "make up for someone"?

Tags: phrases

I have a question about the phrase "make up for".

You can make up for the loss, the delay or someone's mistake, right? I used to think you can also "make (this/it) up for someone", meaning that you will do something nice to that person because you feel obligated for your not-so-nice conduct prior to this conversation.

ex) Hey, I'm sorry I'm late. I will totally make this up for you.

Since I can't seem to find a valid example for this usage, I noticed that I might have picked up this phrase mistakenly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are thinking of is *[make it up to somebody](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/make-it-up-to-sb)*. That means to do something good for someone you have upset to be on good terms with them again.

Comment: The implication being if you *make **it up to** someone*, you're actively counterbalancing something *(it?)* you did wrong in the past. Whereas if you *make **up with** them*, there's no implication that either party is more blameworthy, or puts more effort into the reconciliation than the other.

Comment: In formal contexts, "reconcile" / "reconciliation" could be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The correct phrase is "*I'll make it up to you.*"

> Hey, I'm sorry I'm late. I will totally **make this up to you**.